# Map bounded if composition is bounded. (Proof verification)

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces

Is this proof valid?

#### Problem

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Let $S: X \to X$ be linear, bounded and injective. Let $T:X \to X$ be linear. Show that if $ST$ is bounded, then $T$ is bounded.

#### Proof

Claim: $T$ is closed.

Let $(x_i), (T x_i)$ be sequences such that $x_i \to x$ and $Tx_i \to y$. I need to show that $T x = y$.

$$||STx - Sy|| \le ||STx - STx_i||  + ||STx_i -Sy||$$
$$ \le ||ST||||x-x_i|| + ||S|| || Tx_i - y|| \to 0$$

as $i \to \infty$. Hence $||STx - Sy|| = 0 \implies STx = Sy$. Since $S$ is injective, we get that $Tx = y$, hence $T$ is closed. By the closed graph theorem, $T$ is continuous, i.e. bounded. $\square$

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: It looks fine to me.